# Multicore Multinode example for caret in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, r-caret

I am looking for a multi-node + multi-core example for training a model using caret. I currently use the multi-core functionality and it works quite well, but for certain tasks that require a lot of iterations, I was wondering if it is possible to leverage a multi-node setup whereby I can train in parallel across all the cores of all the nodes. So, if I have 2 nodes of 24 core each, instead of training on single node with 24 cores, I would train using 48 cores leveraging both the nodes.

Is there any existing functionality that achieves this / does it have to be coded manually,

Thanks,

- Raj.

Comment: I am aware of the SNOW package, but have never used it in this multinode+multicore method via caret.

Comment: I've never done it, but it should be possible. Caret just uses foreach to run resampling in parallel and foreach can be setup across multiple nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow caret to use multiple nodes and multiple cores you need to create and register the appropriate foreach parallel backend. You can do that with the doSNOW package by creating a snow cluster that starts multiple workers per node by specifying the same hostname multiple times. To start 24 workers per node, you could use:

```
library(doSNOW)
cl <- makeSOCKcluster(c(rep('node1', 24), rep('node2', 24)))
registerDoSNOW(cl)
```

The `makeSOCKcluster` function uses ssh to start the workers, so you should set up password-less ssh. That can be difficult (impossible?) to do on Windows, but it's commonly done on Linux and Mac OS X. If you're using a Linux cluster, it may be better to use `makeMPIcluster`.